# Finding an object and returning it based on search criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have been searching online all day and I cant seem to find my answer.  (and I know that there must be a way to do this in javascript).

Basically, I want to be able to search through an array of objects and return the object that has the information I need.

Example:

Each time someone connects to a server:

```
var new_client = new client_connection_info(client_connect.id, client_connect.remoteAddress, 1);

function client_connection_info ( socket_id, ip_address, client_status) {
    this.socket_id=socket_id;
    this.ip_address=ip_address;
    this.client_status=client_status; // 0 = offline 1 = online
};
```

Now, I want to be able to search for "client_connection.id" or "ip_address", and bring up that object and be able to use it.  Example:

```
var results = SomeFunction(ip_address, object_to_search);
print_to_screen(results.socket_id);
```

I am new to javascript, and this would help me dearly!

Comment: What does your `object_to_search` look like?

Comment: You're gonna need to make a loop, loop through each element, and check if the `ip_address` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Have you looked into converting the data from JSON and looking it up as you would in a dictionary? (in case you don't know, that would look like object['ip_address'])

jQuery has a function for this jQuery.parseJSON(object).

Comment: JSON is a *string representation* of a JavaScript object.  You're suggesting he use a JavaScript object, not JSON.

Comment: It's ok.  It's just kinda bugs me when people mix that up :-P

Comment: How would `parseJSON` help here?  He doesn't have a JSON string anywhere.

Comment: http://blog.webonweboff.com/2010/05/javascript-search-array-of-objects.html

I have tried this, but it always returns "-1", even tho I manually placed the information in there to test it out.

Comment: @Rocket, I read "object of arrays" and immediately thought "JSON", but now that I reread I'm getting kind of confused about what the object is that OP is getting/searching. OP says "object of arrays" but I don't see an array anywhere in the sample object. OP, do you mean "array of objects"?

Comment: OH, ok. Yeah, that makes a big difference :) Rocket's answer should work, but I'm curious as to why yours didn't. You don't have a jsfiddle on it, do you?

Comment: Nope, I dont have a jsfiddle on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply want a selector method, assuming I understood your problem correctly:

```
 function where(array, predicate)
 {
     var matches = [];
     for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        if(predicate(j))
           matches.push(j);

     return matches;
 }
```

Then you could simply call it like so:

```
  var sample = [];

  for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
     sample.push(j);

  var evenNumbers = where(sample, function(elem)
  {
       return elem % 2 == 0;
  });
```

If you wanted to find a specific item:

```
  var specificguy = 6;

  var sixNumber = where(sample, function(elem)
  {
       return elem == specificguy;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to loop through your array, and stop when you find the object you want.

```
var arr = [new_client, new_client2, new_client3]; // array of objects
var found; // variable to store the found object
var search = '127.0.0.1'; // what we are looking for
for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){ // loop through array
    var x = arr[i]; // get current object
    if(x.ip_address === search){ // does this object contain what we want?
        found = x;  // store the object
        break; // stop looping, we've found it
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example works, but then I would have to know which object to search from, right?  If so, does that mean I have to make linked list? To be able to accomplish what I need.

Comment: What do you by "which object to search from" and "make link-lists"?

Comment: If I did: A=new client_connection_info(1,1,1) & B=new client_connection_info(2,2,2), I would have to make arr = [A,B], but if I already knew A and B, then I wouldn't have to search through them.  So, what I need to do is make arr = all objects of client_connection_info, and search through all those objects to find a match.  link-lists(linked lists): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: @user1328762: There's no way to get all objects of `client_connection_info` into an array.  The **only** way to get an array of `client_connection_info` objects, is to make one, and push the objects into it.  There are no linked lists in JavaScript, only objects and arrays.

Comment: @user1328762: If you know the objects, why did you ask this question in the first place?  If you already have you object, why search for it?  I'm really confused >.<

Comment: I don't know the objects, what if someone sends me a message containing an ip_address and tells me to disconnect them from the server.  I would then search for the socket that contains the ip_address, and disconnect them.  That ip_address is stored in client_connection_info that is made each time someone connects to the server.

Comment: Where are you storing these "sockets" or "client_connection_info" objects?  You need to store them _somewhere_.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I had to store objects when I make a new one.  If two people connect to my server, wouldn't there be client_connection_info[2]?

Comment: `client_connection_info` is a function, not an array.  It doesn't know how many instances of it there are.  `new client_connection_info` makes a new object.  It doesn't store it anywhere, that's up to you.

Comment: Oh, I see my problem now.  How do I go about storing these?

Comment: @user1328762: You can store them in an array `var connections = [A,B]`.  Or you can use an object `var connections = {ip_addressA: A, ip_addressB: B}`.  I suggest using an object, with the `ip_address` as the key.  That way you can find objects quickly by doing `connections['127.0.0.1']`.